# send request from jsp to servlet using gson

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, gson

I am developing a web application using *JSP*, *Servlets*. I am using `gson` for sending request from *jqGrid* to *Servlet*.

Following is my code to send request to Servlet:

**JSP**

```
$.post('MyServletName?action=Activate&var11='+var11,
    function(responseJson) 
    {
        $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) 
        {
            alert(item);
        });
    });
```

**Servlet Code**

```
String str= request.getParameter("var11");
```

I am able to send the request to *Servlet* using above code. But if `var11` contains  `%` , then it is not sending the `%` sign and all characters after `%` to the *Servlet*.

So Please let me know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` (and other special characters in URLs) needs to be encoded. If you use the (optional) `data` parameter of the `jQuery.post()` function this will be handled for you. So change it to:

```
$.post('MyServletName?action=Activate', {var11 : var11}, function (responseJson) {
    $.each(responseJson, function (index, item) {
        alert(item);
    });
});
```

You could alternatively use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function, like so:

```
$.post('MyServletName?action=Activate&var11=' + encodeURIComponent(var11), function (responseJson) {
    $.each(responseJson, function (index, item) {
        alert(item);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the quotes for var11 attribute `{"var11":var11}` instead of `{var11:var11}` if you choose the first method.